# Is there a way to annotate a bash's encoding in its shebang?

Tags: linux, bash, encoding, utf-8, terminal

I wrote a bash like the one below, and it echoes nicely in the Linux terminal, since I encoded the file with UTF-8:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Olá, möndo!'
```

I'm required to let users choose whatever encoding they see fit, while still printing the correct diacritics in the terminal, but since the terminal is default to UTF-8, any other encoding produces all sorts of bizarre characters.

So, the problem is: How are the users supposed to annotate the bash's encoding in the file? Does bash have a pattern to let us do so?

---

I'm aware that `file -I` detects the encoding of a file almost correctly, but the bashes in question are executed in the regular fashion way `./foo.sh`. So, it would be nice if the terminal could detect the encoding by itself.

Comment: It works the other way round. Your script knows the encoding of the terminal from locale, so it should output text that is in that encoding. It's not terminal detecting your script, is your script providing translations for different encodings.

Comment: I think the question you need to ask first is: when the user does specify the encoding, what program is going to convert the output to the correct output encoding (and, for that matter, how will that program know what _is_ the correct output encoding?) Find an answer to that, and the way to build it into the script may answer itself.

Comment: I understand. Sometimes I just can't get them changing the settings in their apps but I can encourage them to at least write the encoding down to the file.

Answer (score 2):

It works the other way round. Your script knows the encoding the user **wants** to have in his messages from locale `LC_MESSAGES`, so your script should accordingly output text that is in that encoding. It's not terminal detecting your script, is your script providing translations of it's messages for different encodings. `LC_MESSAGES` *should* also have encoding information, so `LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8` is not `LC_MESSAGESen_US.EBCDIC`.

The usual way to provide translations is via [`gettext`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html). Bash comes with a builtin `gettext` support (but it still needs **a lot** of work to make it usable) with its `$"..."` strings support, see [locale translations](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Locale-Translation.html).

Comment: This completely solves the problem:

`#!/usr/bin/env LC_ALL=en_US.ISO-8859-1 bash`

And the users are generaly aware of the encoding they are writing in.
I'm willing to go with that. Do you see a reason why I shouldn't?

Comment: @GugaCoder That won't solve it, because the encoding the terminal expects/understands may be different from the script's encoding, and that doesn't do anything about translating between them. But it's even worse than that, because the encoding used for filenames may be something different from the script's and/or the terminal's, and if you need to interact with textish content within files, that may be different again... and every time text from one of these contexts moves to a different context, you may need an explicit translation step.

Comment: I see the implication. I edit my question to reflect your thought. It seems to work though so I'm going to investigate further so what happens.

Comment: you're right, I see all sorts of strange things happening.

Comment: @GugaCoder Depending on the OS and terminal program you're using, you might be able to configure it to use the same encoding the script does using one of the methods given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87227/switch-encoding-of-terminal-with-a-command) (but remember to set it back afterward). That wouldn't help with filenames or file contents, though.

Comment: Alternately, you could have people add a standardized-format comment as the second line of the script (e.g. `#Charset: ISO-8859-1`), and then write yourself a converter script that'll read that comment and translate the script into *your* preferred charset (and also adjust the comment to match).

Answer (score 1):

For a more pedestrian solution, you can use `iconv` to convert on the fly. Assuming you can extract the user's preferred encoding from their locale settings into `$enc`, then simply

```sh
echo 'Olá, möndo!' | iconv -f utf-8 -t "$enc"
```